# Compare two unequal column matrix in matlab without using for loop

Tags: matlab

I want to compare two columns matrix : such as

```
a=[1;2;2;3;4;4;5;6] 
b=[2;4;8]
```

and get the output like

```
d=[0;1;1;0;1;1;0;0]
```

which is same number of rows of matrix `a`.

Answer (score 5):

[`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) is exact what you need. Try:

```
  c=ismember(a,b)
```